# How to disable text selection in embeded pdf in html page?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I'm developing an e-library website and I want to display book content (saved in pdf format). The problem is the user that open embeded pdf still able to copy the content by highlight the text. Where do I need to set the code?

I already put `style="width:100%; height:100%; user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;"`

this is my current code

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/ci_crud/upload/product/Proposal_Thesis.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" title="PDF in an i-Frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="width:100%; height:100%; user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. And even if, what for? Users could still screenshot the PDF or copy/type the contents to somewhere else.

Comment: @kerbholz that my client request